# CSS/Jquery OverFlow Hidden not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a quick slider here that is giving me some trouble on initial page load.
The Overflow suppose to be hidden but when it loads- right part of the hidden div shows for about 1 second before it is hidden.

I also have a Fiddle Link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EXevB/5/show/

As you load the page you can see the hidden segment on the right shows quickly for about 1 second. I'm trying to avoid this- Thanks for any help in Advance.

Thanks You

JS:
    var w = 0;

```
$('.mainSlide').children().each(function() {
    w += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('.outer').width(w);
$('.wrap').width(w);
$('.mainSlide').css('left', '480px');

$('.open').toggle(function() {
    $('.mainSlide').stop().animate({left: 0});
    $(this).html('');
    $('.content-text').css('display', 'block');

}, function() {

    $('.mainSlide').stop().animate({left: 480});
    $('.content-text').css('display', 'none');

    $(this).html('OPEN');
});
```

Comment: What-oh-what is that image of?

Comment: You should use another more solid code for your slider, as:
`<ul>
<li>slide1</li>
<li>slide2</li>
</ul>`

Comment: Damn "enter" key sending my comment! :P I was saying, using that structure, you shouls set via css that the ul elem has the with of all the li's added up. Then you put that in a wrapper with the width of a single li and OVERFLOW HIDDEN. Then you just move the ul's left property ;)

Comment: Any Clear Solution more thoughts here?

Comment: Your code's a little hard for me to follow, but often when I see this kind of situation it's the result of setting styles with JS rather than with CSS. It can take a moment for js to load, and your stylesheet rules tend to load faster. So I would move the initial styles to the CSS file and then set JS to override them if needed. That is, the way you want the page to appear when loaded should be determined by your style sheet, not your js code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 <div id="back" class="" style="background: transparent url('http://a.espncdn.com/photo/2013/0209/nba_jordan_00.jpg');height: 257px;
    width: 800px;">

</div>
</div>
<script>
    var w = 0;
    $('#back').html('<div id="dawrap" class="wrap">'+
    '<a class="open" href="#">OPEN</a>'+
    '<div class="outer">'+
       ' <div class="mainSlide">'+
        '<a>'+
         '<img class="content-text" src="" style="margin-left:77px; margin-top:31px; display:none;" />'+
         '<br> <br>'+
         'CONTENT at Default'+
            '</a>'+
        '</div>'+
   ' </div>');
$('.mainSlide').children().each(function() {
    w += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('.outer').width(w);
$('.wrap').width(w);
$('.mainSlide').css('left', '480px');

$('.open').toggle(function() {
    $('.mainSlide').stop().animate({left: 0});
    $(this).html('');
    $('.content-text').css('display', 'block');

}, function() {

    $('.mainSlide').stop().animate({left: 480});
    $('.content-text').css('display', 'none');

    $(this).html('OPEN');
});


</script>
```

?

Or, better (but don't know why today on my browsers $('#id').css('display','block') doesn't want to work) you can set the div as invisible and, when the page is loaded, make it visible. If you want to keep your structure.

For example, using z-index let you avoid position:absolute and with a 4 js raws you can do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function domeafavour(){
    if( $('#slider').width()==100) {
        $('#slider').animate({
        width: '600px'},1000);
    }else{
        $('#slider').animate({
        width: '100px'},1000);
    }
}
</script>


 <div id="back" class="" style="background: transparent url('http://a.espncdn.com/photo/2013/0209/nba_jordan_00.jpg');height:257px;width: 800px;">
  <div id="slider" style='cursor:pointer;float:right;height:252;width:100px; z-index:1;background-color:#CF3;'  onClick="domeafavour()">clickme</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tSggb/9/